# Why am I not capturing any ICMP packets on wireshark?

Tags: networking, wireshark, icmp

I am doing a lab where we are meant to ping an address and use wireshark to capture ICMP packets when we ping that address. WHen I run the wireshark capture with the ICMP filter on and ping my address, I capture no packets. ANy idea why I am not capturing any packets?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause is that you didn't select the proper interface.

On the main screen of Wireshark you should see the list of the interfaces and some graph on the interfaces on which there's traffic, that could help you find out which is the correct one.

As you can see on the screenshot below, even on a client computer there can be a lot if interfaces (this is from my MacBook).  You can see there's traffic on the first two interfaces. The first one is (obviously) my WiFi and the second one is a VPN tunnel.

[image]

The other possible causes are:

- incorrect capture filter
- wireshark is not started with admin privileges and cannot access the network card to put it in promiscuous mode
- the PCAP driver needed to capture traffic on the interface is not installed.